# How to use database from sdcard on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

If I use this path to a database on the sdcard, sql will always create and open the database in the data folder of my appication, it won't open the correct one on my sdcard. What do I need to use a path to a database on the sdcard?

```
String mPath = /storage/sdcard1/test.db


mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/mnt/sdcard/<your folder name>/
```

Comment: That doesn't work :(
It still uses the database in /data/data/myPackage/database

Comment: Where is your database located on your device?

Comment: What is the make of your device and compiled SDK version?

Comment: I found the solution..
I have to set the path in the constructor too:

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator+DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? Its database Version

        this.mContext = context;
    }

Comment: before i had just DB_NAME without the exact path..
thanks anyway :)